# Javascript populate select applies only for the first target

Tags: javascript, html

I got 2 dropdown menus in my website, one applies when user is in the phone, other is when user is on desktop.I use this code:

```
function populateSelect(target, min, max){
if (!target){
    return false;
}
else {
    var min = min || 0,
        max = max || min + 100;

    select = document.getElementById(target);

    for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i;
        opt.innerHTML = i;
        select.appendChild(opt);
    }
  }
}

populateSelect('howMany6');
```

Both dropdowns share same id:

```
<select class="form-control" id="howMany6" name="mituKeyd6" onChange="paljuKokku()"></select>
```

But javascript only adds options to the mobile version of dropdwon, beacuse mobile code is before desktop code in HTML. How can i make javascript code to add options for both of the dropdown menus?

Comment: *"Both dropdowns share same id:"*... Id must be **unique**.

Comment: Well, i need them to share same id.

Comment: you can't have the same "id" for 2 different elements. use a shared class name if you want to share some style or functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't duplicated ids, keep them unique. Instead use classes to refer groups of elements.

In your case you will need to loop over collection of elements and populate each of them separately.

```js
function populateSelect(target, min, max) {
    if (!target) {
        return false;
    } 
    else {
        var min = min || 0,
            max = max || min + 100,
            select = document.querySelectorAll(target);

        for (var j = 0; j < select.length; j++) {
            for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = i;
                opt.innerHTML = i;
                select[j].appendChild(opt);
            }
        } 
    }
}

populateSelect('.howMany6');
```

```html
<select class="form-control howMany6" name="mituKeyd6" onChange="paljuKokku()"></select>
<select class="form-control howMany6" name="mituKeyd6" onChange="paljuKokku()"></select>
```